# Auto-update download in googlecode hosted project

Tags: svn, hook, google-code

I see an [issue open since '07](http://code.google.com/p/support/issues/detail?id=417) regarding this functionality, which github has had as far as I can remember.  Since you don't seem to have programmatic access to the downloads area (like you do with wiki's)  I'm guessing I'd need something like post-commit hooks.  I see webhooks in my googlecode site, but am not familiar with svn enough to know if this can do what I want it to.

I understand another alternative is to have the download hosted elsewhere, so any suggestion about how to best automate the process (remove the .svn dirs, zip up the folders and files, and push to file hosting) would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interest in googlecode really may have died on the vine... anyway, I'm pleased to have found this link staring me in the face from my project's file interface:
[google-provided ways to automate file uploads, via script or ant task](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ScriptedUploads)